# Упростить дерево стилей css

Tags: css

Как можно упростить стили (паддинг можно применять только к a):

```css
.admin-division-menu > ul > li a.admindivisionmenu-without-clild {padding-left: 20px;}

.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li a.admindivisionmenu-without-clild {padding-left: 30px;}
.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li .admindivisionmenu-child {margin-left: 30px;}

.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a.admindivisionmenu-without-clild {padding-left: 50px;}
.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li .admindivisionmenu-child {margin-left: 50px;}

.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a.admindivisionmenu-without-clild {padding-left: 70px;}
.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li .admindivisionmenu-child {margin-left: 70px;}

.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a.admindivisionmenu-without-clild {padding-left: 90px;}
.admin-division-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li .admindivisionmenu-child {margin-left: 90px;}
```

Comment: Навесить классы вида level-n на ul

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не правильный ответ... Что, если использовать `em` для твоей проблемы?

em - изменения относительно размера шрифта элемента (2em означает 2-кратный размер текущего шрифта).

Полезная ссылка
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

```css
ul > li{
margin-left: 1.2em;
padding-left: 1.2em;
font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    lol
    <ul>
      <li>
        lol
        <ul>
          <li>
            lol
            <ul>
              <li>
                lol
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```